# Formatting R output in an R Markdown documents

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a code that generates a text output. For example:

```
pick <- sample(c("Alex", "Greta", "Zoe"), 1)
```

Is there a way of formatting the result in an R Markdown documents.

Say something like this if I wanted it to appear in bold on the report.

```
**pick**
```

Comment: If a chunk is meant to generate markdown text that should then be interpreted by `pandoc`, then you should be able to use [`results='asis'`](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results) as a chunk option.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute any R command in-text in an rmarkdown document without embedding it inside a chunk by placing it within ticks prefaced by the letter `r` (see below). You can then surround this r code with latex code, in this `\bf{foo}` for bold font, bookmarked by `$`. Try placing

```
The OP's chosen name is $\bf{`r sample(c("Alex", "Greta", "Zoe"), 1)`}$
```

inside an rmarkdown document. Or you could place the function in a chunk and then call it outside the chunk, anywhere in subsequent text, like this

```
The OP's chosen name is $\bf{`r pick`}$
```